# Measuring volume using DSM instead of point clouds in Pix4D

Tags: volume, point-cloud, pix4d

I've go a point cloud generated in the Pix4D software from about 90 aerial images. I am trying to measure piles of coal and have found that using the volume measuring tool on the point cloud model generated can be quite inaccurate. This is because of issues such as multiple outlying points appearing above a coal pile, which then introduces artifacts like spikes. This then leads to inaccurate volume measurement of such piles.

Is it therefore possible to use the DSM (how do we obtain in from within Pix4D?) to measure volume instead, as it has the effect of smoothing out such spikes and creates a homogeneous surface?

Comment: Isn't a DSM in tiff format a direct output of Pix4D? And what other GIS software do you have?

Comment: Found it, thank you! I am new to the product so am still getting used to the functions and outputs. I am currently also using QGIS and ENVI. Would either of those softwares help properly display the DSM (ie. 3-dimentional representation)?

Answer (score 2):

here's some good news for you!
In the latest version of Pix4Dmapper, ***the volume is calculated based on the DSM*** ***if the 3rd step - DSM and Orthomosaic generation is done***. This is done by default, and users do not have to change any settings! 
Please stay tuned :)

Lisa

Comment: Many thanks for that, Lisa! May I just ask where in the Pix4D documentation did you spot that?